# Notification not working for custom reply button react native

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, custom-notification

I have created few channels for different notifications in my MainActivity.java in one of the channel i want to activate reply from notification feature

For Custom reply button using Notification Compat to build the notification but it is not working

here is my code in Main activity

````
public class Main Activity extends React Activity {

    private static final String CHANNEL_ID_REMARKS = "remarks channel";
    private static final String CHANNEL_ID_ALARM = "alarm_channel";
    public static final String REPLY_ACTION = "com.appname.REPLY_ACTION";
    public static final String KEY_TEXT_REPLY = "key_text_reply";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    
        createNotificationChannels();
        
        super.onCreate((savedInstanceState));
    }

    private void createNotificationChannels() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

            NotificationChannel tokyoChannel = new NotificationChannel("tokyo_channel", "{appname}}", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            tokyoChannel.setShowBadge(true);
            tokyoChannel.setDescription("");
            AudioAttributes atttokyo = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SPEECH)
                    .build();
            tokyoChannel.setSound(Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/tokyo"), atttokyo);
            tokyoChannel.enableVibration(true);
            tokyoChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{400, 400});
            tokyoChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);

            NotificationChannel remarksChannel = new NotificationChannel("remarks_Channel", "{appname}}", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            remarksChannel.setShowBadge(true);
            remarksChannel.setDescription("");
            AudioAttributes attremarks = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SPEECH)
                    .build();
            remarksChannel.setSound(Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/alarm"), attremarks);
            remarksChannel.enableVibration(true);
            remarksChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{400, 400});
            remarksChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);

            NotificationChannel alarmChannel = new NotificationChannel("alarm_channel", "{appname}}", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            alarmChannel.setShowBadge(true);
            alarmChannel.setDescription("");
            AudioAttributes attalarm = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SPEECH)
                    .build();
            alarmChannel.setSound(Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/alarm"), attalarm);
            alarmChannel.enableVibration(true);
            alarmChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{400, 400});
            alarmChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);

            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);

            manager.createNotificationChannel(tokyoChannel);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(remarksChannel);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(alarmChannel);
        
        }
    }```


here it is for reply reciver
````

public class ReplyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (MyFirebaseMessagingService.REPLY_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Bundle remoteInput = RemoteInput.getResultsFromIntent(intent);
        if (remoteInput != null) {
            String replyText = remoteInput.getCharSequence(MyFirebaseMessagingService.KEY_TEXT_REPLY).toString();
            Toast.makeText(context, "Reply: " + replyText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.cancel(1); =
        }
    }
}
```

}```